# is PDO execute function is limited to accept arguments?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a working pdo integrated database class. All of my queries are working very efficiently but when I try to pass a certain value, I got stuck. This value is:

```
DATE_SUB('2010-11-03', INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

Now after all my working of class query is prepared like:

```
SELECT DATE(added) AS date FROM data WHERE DATE(added) <= ?
```

When i m trying to pass the value: `DATE_SUB('2010-11-03', INETRVAL 30 DAY)` to `execute()` function,no result is received(but query is executing successfully).

i tried sending raw value '`2010-11-03'`. Its working correctly but not wid this function.
Do anybody know y this mysql function is not being passed to execute function?

Comment: The  typo in `INETRVAL` is accidental?

Comment: Anyway, can you show in more clarity what the problem is? Is it that you can't parametrize the INTERVAL value? Can you show the full code?

Comment: oh itz interval only....but problem is i have to fynd the closest date to a specific date in a database stored date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use placeholders as a *replace this portion of my SQL query* : placeholders and their corresponding bound values, can only correspond to values.

When you're passing `2010-11-03`, you're passing a value -- so it works.

When you're trying to pass `DATE_SUB('2010-11-03', INTERVAL 30 DAY)`, it's not a value -- so it doesn't work.

Here, you'll have to rewrite your Prepared statement, so the placeholder corresponds to the date, and not a whole expression :

```
SELECT DATE(added) AS date 
FROM data 
WHERE DATE(added) <= DATE_SUB(?, INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

*(The `30` could also be replaced with a placeholder, if needed)*

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DATE(added) AS date 
  FROM data 
 WHERE DATE(added) <= DATE_SUB(?, INTERVAL ? DAY)
```

and treat both the date and interval as bind values

Comment: dear its a class and accepting where values as array('DATE(added)' => DATE_SUB('2010-11-03'), INTERVAL 30 DAY).

Comment: and generating query accordingly..i cant use your method..i was thinking that it will placed as a string ..plz guide in this context

Comment: @Aakash why do you need to pass the whole string? Why not do it as @Mark shows?